# Incentive theme - Getting ’You do not have sufficient permissions’ while trying to install plugins

Tags: plugins, themes

After making a clean install of wordpress and theme folowwing the installation guidelines from readme.html, I can not install the WPBakery Visual Composer and Revolution Slider plugins because I get an ‘You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page’

I have not modified anything on Wordpress and in all the installation, it is a new and clean installation. All the server directories have full perms (write, read and execute).

I have tried removing all the wordpress instalation and installing again (database removed included) but I get the same error.

I'm working on wordpress 4.0

Comment: Are you logged in as ADMIN?

Comment: Yes! the installed wordpress has just an user, and this is mine. I have installed other plugins withouth problems...

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin authors

Comment: Well, the plugin installation is mandatory with the theme, so I have contacted with the theme author but they say it's not a  problem theme